# Why can't I get the container width without the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a container (masonry grid) with some images. I have a function to calculate the the width of the container and an other function to calculate the width of each image. But the function to get the container width, doesn't work as excpected, because the width contains the scrollbar. Therefore the calculation of the images width is also incorrect.

```
//Function to calculate the width of the container
 getContainerWidth() {
    const postContainer = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'container'
    );
    if (postContainer.length > 0) {
      let containerWidth = postContainer[0].clientWidth;
      containerWidth = `${containerWidth}px`;

      this.setState({
        containerWidth: containerWidth,
      });
    }
  }
```

I have already tried verious functions (offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth...) but none of them worked for me. I have also tried to get the width of the scrollbar and subtract it from the container width. This worked, but I need a solution which works on different Browsers.

If the browser width is for example 1920px. Then the container-width is also 1920px, but it should be 1905px (1920 - scrollbar).

Comment: Put a container inside of your container, then put the picture inside of the inner container, what does that do? Does it include the width with the bar as well?

Comment: I have already a container outside. I have a container which contains a header, footer and the container which contains the images. And both outside container and container with images include the scrollbar

Comment: If hiding the scrollbar is an option use `::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0px; }` then calculate the width

Answer (score 0):

Get the [ClientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes, otherwise it's the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but not the vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered), border or margin.

Example

```
var width = element.clientWidth;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `px` instead of something like '`100%`? Maybe that's an easier way.

Comment: I need the containter in px, because I use it to calculate the image width. I subtract the marign between the items and then I divide the result with the number of columns. If I have for example 4 columns and a container width of 1920px. Then I subtract 3x20px (gap between items). Then I divide the result (1860px) with the number of columns(4). The result is the width of each image (465px).